# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech WaveNet API Character conversion rate

Tags: google-text-to-speech

What is the character or word conversion rate for Google Cloud’s Text-to-Speech WaveNet API? I want to know rough timestamps for long WaveNet generated audio files. I could use even a rough estimation.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 0.5s to convert about 150 characters.

That's the size of blocks I convert. Can't say how much of that is the invocation overhead. I.e. it may be more efficient with larger amounts of text to generate audio.

Comment: _it may be more efficient with larger amounts of text to generate audio_ - it is.